# How do I amend all values in a column to a fixed 9 digits and the results of each beginning with a constant int 405 eg.51=405000051

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to export some customer balances from a table and import to another. However the customer_ID column is not fixed and need to be, the values are anywhere from 3 to 5 digits (eg.322…4144…11833).

I would like to export the data with the customer_ID and customer_bals to a csv where the values in the customer_id column are fixed to 9 digits all starting with a constant 405 at the beginning of each value. Such as eg. 405000322…405004144 and 405011833.

How would I write this query in MySQL Workbench?

Comment: `SELECT 405000000 + customer_ID FROM table`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LPAD` function to add leading zeroes, and `CONCAT()` to concatenate the fixed prefix.

```
CONCAT('405', LPAD(customerID, 6, '0'))
```